# How can I optimize this SQLAlchemy delete query for the Match table, which deletes rows where both user_id and partner_id match a specific user_id?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's my current code:

```
async def delete_match(user_id):
    async with session_pool() as session:
        delete_stmt = delete(Match).where(Match.user_id == user_id)
        delete_stmt = delete(Match).where(Match.partner_id == user_id)
        await session.execute(delete_stmt)
        await session.commit()
        print(f"Matches deleted for user ID {user_id}")
```

here is my model

```
class Match(Base, TableNameMixin):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    partner_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, nullable=False)
```

Is there a more efficient and faster way to achieve this? Additionally, what would be an efficient way to save the last 3 match IDs for a `user_id`?

Comment: "*to save the last 3 match IDs for a user_id*" - do you mean to delete all except the last 3 matches ?

Comment: I think i had made it little confusing. I just want to record last 3  match id of each user  so they can rematch and make db less heavy.

Comment: but you are trying to delete all matches

Comment: I cant figure out what will be good way. Can u help out,